# .NET 6 Table 'aspnetuserroles' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, .net, asp.net-core, identity, user-roles

I'm configuring a new project on .NET 6, with jwt, identity and MySQL Mariadb with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.2.
The error I'm getting when I try to login is "Table 'aspnetuserroles' doesn't exist". That table doesn't exist, but because I renamed it from OnModelCreating(). I searched on internet and the solution they give is to add "base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);" on ApplicationDbContext, and then use ".ToTable()" to change the name of the table but I did this and still with the same problem.
This is all my configuration if anyone can help:

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario, Rol, string>
{
    protected readonly string ConnectionString;
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }
    public ApplicationDbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(options);
        options.LogTo(message => Debug.WriteLine(message), new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name })
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseMySql(ConnectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString));
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Usuario> IdentityUser { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("usuarios");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("usuarioroles").HasKey("RoleId", "UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey("UserId", "ProviderKey", "LoginProvider");

    }

}
```

The connectionString its ok because I can get the user from db, but the error is when I try to use userManager to get the roles from that user.

I tried to change the table name from UsuarioConfig file, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>().ToTable("usuarios");
```

I think this works

Why am I not using `IdentityUser<TKey>`
Because I'm using `db first`, so when I tried to use `IdentityUser<TKey>`, I found that it doesn't work.

The specific reason, I think this is an interesting question.
Maybe we need to look at the source code or documentation

Answer (score 0):

When you wanna change the name of these tables (IdentityUserRole <`Tkey`>、 IdentityUserToken <`Tkey`>、 IdentityRoleClaim <`Tkey`>、 IdentityUserClaim <`Tkey`>、 IdentityUserLogin <`Tkey`>), you need to specify the type of `T`(The type used for the primary key ),

So change your code to:

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserRoles");
             
            });
```

Then you can check the name of table has been changed

[image]

More information please refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-the-model).